# How do I return error from a Future in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

In my flutter app, I have a future that handles http requests and returns the decoded data. But I want to be able to send an error if the `status code != 200` that can be gotten with the `.catchError()` handler.

**Heres the future:**

```
Future<List> getEvents(String customerID) async {
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull(...)
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }else{
    // I want to return error here 
  }
}
```

and when I call this function, I want to be able to get the error like:

```
getEvents(customerID)
.then(
  ...
).catchError(
  (error) => print(error)
);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `throw` :

```
Future<List> getEvents(String customerID) async {
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull(...)
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }else{
    // I want to return error here 
       throw("some arbitrary error"); // error thrown
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having `Exception has occurred.` on `throw("some arbitrary error");`

Comment: i've been confused why the asker mark this answer. but how to throw the error from `then()` block and catch it at caller future's `catchError()` block? just like in the question

Answer (score 118):

#### Throwing an error/exception:

You can use either `return` or `throw` to throw an error or an exception.

- ###### Using `return`:

  ```dart
  Future<void> foo() async {
    if (someCondition) {
      return Future.error('FooError');
    }
  }
  ```
- ###### Using `throw`:

  ```dart
  Future<void> bar() async {
    if (someCondition) {
      throw Exception('BarException');
    }
  }
  ```

---

#### Catching the error/exception:

You can use either `catchError` or `try-catch` block to catch the error or the exception.

- ###### Using `catchError`:

  ```dart
  foo().catchError(print);
  ```
- ###### Using `try-catch`:

  ```dart
  try {
    await bar();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  ```

Comment: well, where are the examples? my use case is with `await`. Not sure how to use `catchError` with `await`, isn't clear

Comment: @Toskan wrap it in a try block. That's why there are two forms

Comment: that means I _cannot_ use await if the function returns `return Future.error`? as there is no way to catch the error. Seems like a weakness to me

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve this is by using the [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz) package.

An example of how to use it would look something similar like this

```
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

abstract class Failure {}
class ServerFailure extends Failure {}
class ResultFailure extends Failure {
  final int statusCode;
  const ResultFailure({required this.statusCode});
}

FutureOr<Either<Failure, List>> getEvents(String customerID) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(...)
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Right(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      return Left(ResultFailure(statusCode: response.statusCode)); 
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    return Left(ServerFailure());  
  }
}

main() async {
  final result = await getEvents('customerId');
  result.fold(
    (l) => print('Some failure occurred'),
    (r) => print('Success')
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return the error data like this if you want to read the error object:

```
response = await dio.post(endPoint, data: data).catchError((error) {
  return error.response;
});
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

//POST

```
Future<String> post_firebase_async({String? path , required Product product}) async {
    final Uri _url = path == null ? currentUrl: Uri.https(_baseUrl, '/$path');

    print('Sending a POST request at $_url');

    final response = await http.post(_url, body: jsonEncode(product.toJson()));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
      return result['name'];
    }
    else{
      //throw HttpException(message: 'Failed with ${response.statusCode}');
      return Future.error("This is the error", StackTrace.fromString("This is its trace"));
    }

  }
```

Here is how to call:

```
  final result = await _firebase.post_firebase_async(product: dummyProduct).
  catchError((err){
    print('huhu $err');
  });
```