# Why catchError isn't able to catch the error?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    print('Error caught = $error');
  });
}

Future<void> foo() {
  throw Future.error('FooError');
}
```

As I read the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/DelegatingFuture/catchError.html):

> This is the asynchronous equivalent of a "catch" block.

If I use `catch` block, the error is caught. But my `catchError` isn't able to catch the error, but according to docs it should. Am I doing something wrong?

---

Note: I know I can use `return` instead of `throw` and the error will be then caught in `catchError` as stated by @CopsOnRoad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736915/6618622). My question is why `catchError` isn't catching a thrown error but `catch` block does catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo()` throws an error before it returns the `Future` to the caller. So it's not that `catchError` isn't working, the error is just not passed back to the caller.

If you mark `foo` as `async` so that the function actually returns a `Future`, you'll see that the error is caught.

```dart
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    print('Error caught = $error');
  });
}

Future<void> foo() async {
  throw Future.error('FooError');
}
```

You'll see from the accepted answer of your [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54474804/13250142) that their function is marked `async` so that a `Future` is actually returned that `catchError` can catch.

Having a function that returns `Future<void>` without being marked `async` and not returning a literal type of `Future<void>` really should be an error.