# How to get the value from Future.error inside catchError?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    if (error is Future) {
      error.then((value) => print('value = $value'));
    }
  });
}

Future<void> foo() async {
  throw Future.error('FooError');
}
```

The error is caught inside `catchError` but I am not able to retrieve the value of `Future.error` which is `FooError` in this example.

Comment: Why would you do that? Either return the Future.error, or throw the error directly without the Future?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's `Future.error` so you'll have to again use `catchError` on it.

```dart
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    if (error is Future) {
      error.catchError((error) => print(error)); // prints 'FooError'
    }
  });
}

Future<void> foo() async {
  throw Future.error('FooError');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't, there is no point in doing so.

You can either throw the error:

```
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    print('error = $error');
  });
}

Future<void> foo() async {
  throw 'FooError';
}
```

Or if that is for whatever reason not convinient, you can use `Future.error` to create a Future that will have an error already:

```
void main() {
  foo().catchError((error) {
    print('error = $error');
  });
}

Future<void> foo() {
  return Future.error('FooError');
}
```

But actually `throw`ing a `Future.error` is redundant and not useful.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63560652/12483095) and someone provided an answer to it, but when I was printing it on console, I was seeing `Instance of Future<dynamic>`, so I decided to use `then` on that `error` but it wasn't printing the value, so I released I had to again use `catchError` on it.

Comment: So, this post doesn't have any significance in real world problems as you should `return Future.error` instead of throwing it. You can however throw an `Exception` and that would work just fine.

Comment: Well, yeah. Instead of describing how to handle a bad piece of code, just don't write a bad piece of code in the first place.