# flutter firestore setData no error if no network connection is available

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code:

```
createOrder(Order order) {
    loading.add(true);
    _auth.currentUser().asStream().asyncMap((FirebaseUser user) async {
      DocumentReference ref = firestore.collection('orders').document();

      order = order.copyWith(
          uid: user.uid,
          createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          updatedAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

      return await ref.setData(order.toJson()).catchError((e){
        print('OrderBloc catchError: ${e.toString()}');
        loading.add(false);
        errors.add(ErrorHandler.handle(e));
      });
    }).listen((data) {
      loading.add(false);
      createOrderSubject.add(null);
    }).onError((e) {
      print('OrderBloc: ${e.toString()}');
      loading.add(false);
      errors.add(ErrorHandler.handle(e));
    });
  }
```

The problem is that it doesn't call neither `catchError` nor `onError` when there is no internet connection available on the device.

So the result is that the loading spinner just keeps spinning forever.

I see this error in the logs: 
`I/OkHttpClientTransport(16453): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7f6856b188: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe`

So why the onError and catch error don't get executed? How to fix it?

Comment: The `_auth.currentUser()` only gets a value if the user signed in, or failed to sign in. If there's no network connection, neither of those cases is true. You'll typically want to either detect the lack of network connection before calling `_auth.currentUser()`, or put a time-out in the code to give up trying.

Comment: What about the SSLException, it's not getting caught, why?

Comment: If there's a problem establishing a secure connection, that is likely happening on the client-side. That would normally throw a regular exception, while `onError` is used for errors that happen on the server.

Comment: Is there a way to catch a client side exception in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721661/how-to-catch-exception-in-flutter?

Answer (score 1):

FlutterFire [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) has offline data persistence enabled by default as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#configure-offline-persistence). This should automatically handle operations when the device regains network connectivity.

If you need to check if the device is currently connected to a network, you may consider using [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin.

```dart
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Handle network connectivity status
    // https://pub.dev/documentation/connectivity_plus_platform_interface/latest/connectivity_plus_platform_interface/ConnectivityResult.html
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // Not connected to network
    }
  });
}

// Be sure to cancel subscription once done
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  subscription.cancel();
}
```